# geom_text with rounded percentage numbers on a bar graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, rounding, geom-text

I am trying to achieve a bar graph with percentages shown, but can not round them down.

In this variant the percentages are shown, but I am not able to round them

```
ggplot(data=true_dizzy, aes(x = reorder(factor(ICD_subgroup_new), ICD_subgroup_new, length), 
                            y = prop.table(stat(count)), 
                            label = scales::percent(prop.table(stat(count))))) +
  geom_bar() + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_text(stat = "count", position = position_dodge(.9), hjust = 0, size = 3) +
  scale_y_continuous(label = scales::percent) +
  labs(y = c(""), x = c(""), title = c("Subgroups of Dizzy Patients (%")) +
  theme_bw()
```

and in this variant there are no percent signs behind the numbers

```
ggplot(data=true_dizzy, aes(x = reorder(factor(ICD_subgroup_new), ICD_subgroup_new, length), 
                            y = prop.table(stat(count)), 
                            label = scales::percent(prop.table(stat(count))))) +
  geom_bar() + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = round(x = (..count../sum(..count..))*100, digits = 1), hjust = 0),
            position = position_dodge(.9), hjust = 0, size = 3) +
  scale_y_continuous(label = scales::percent) +
  labs(y = c(""), x = c(""), title = c("Subgroups of Dizzy Patients (%")) +
  theme_bw()
```

I know the problem is in the geom_text line, but i cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: There are many questions about labelling bar graphs with percentages. Can you tell us why those didn't answer your particular question?

Comment: @teunbrand, I could not find one that showed how to round the numbers in this context

Comment: Doesn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35763259/11374827) answer your question?

Comment: @tuenbrand, I've tried this, but the numbers end up at the point where the percentage bars would be, while those will not be displayed